# JSON schema allOf

Tags: json, jsonschema

I had a json schema working fine with an allOf condition.  However, I have had to change the structure of the schema and the elements are no longer in the same place as they once were and now I can't seem to figure out why I am getting a valid schema when in reality it should be invalid.  So the example schema is (shortened for clarity but there will be other conditions within the allOf):

```
{
  "$ref": "#/$defs/Schema",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$defs": {
    "Schema": {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "Transaction": {
          "$ref": "#/$defs/Transaction"
        }
      }
    },
    "Transaction": {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "Header": {
          "$ref": "#/$defs/Header"
        },
        "Offer": {
          "$ref": "#/$defs/Offer"
        }
      },
      "required": ["Header"],
      "title": "Transaction"
    },
    "Header": {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "Flow": {
          "$ref": "#/$defs/Flow"
        }
      },
      "allOf": [
        {
          "$ref": "#/$defs/OFFER"
        }
      ]
    },
    "Offer": {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "Offer-Status": {
          "$ref": "#/$defs/Offer-Status"
        }
      }
    },
    "OFFER": {
      "if": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "Transaction": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "Header": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                  "Flow": {
                    "enum": ["Offer"]
                  }
                },
                "required": ["Flow"]
              }
            },
            "required": ["Header"]
          }
        },
        "required": ["Transaction"]
      },
      "then": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "Transaction": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "Offer": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                  "Offer-Status": {
                    "enum": ["NEW"]
                  }
                },
                "required": ["Offer-Status"]
              }
            },
            "required": ["Offer"]
          }
        },
        "required": ["Transaction"]
      }
    },
    "Flow": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": ["Offer", "Acceptance"]
    },
    "Offer-Status": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": ["NEW", ""]
    }
  }
}
```

So essentially, the condition should be that if the Flow element within the Header is set to "Offer" the Offer-Status should be set to required and "NEW".

I have tried many different variations of structure but none have validated successfully.

The input JSON, which should be invalid (but showing as valid) is:

```
{
  "Transaction": {
    "Header": {
      "Flow": "Offer"
    },
    "Offer": {
      // "Offer-Status": "NEW"
    }
  }
}
```

Probably a minor issue that I am just not seeing and hopefully someone can see the problem.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplified to show the general approach for a possible solution. It should be straightforward to add your additional schema parts.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "description": "JSON schema generated with JSONBuddy https://www.json-buddy.com",
  "definitions": {
    "OFFERREQ": {
      "if": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "Header": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "Flow": {
                "enum": [ "Offer" ]
              }
            },
            "required": [ "Flow" ]
          }
        },
        "required": [ "Header" ]
      },
      "then": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "Offer": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "Offer-Status": {
                "enum": [ "NEW" ]
              }
            },
            "required": [ "Offer-Status" ]
          }
        },
        "required": [ "Offer" ]
      }
    }
  },
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "properties": {
    "Transaction": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/OFFERREQ"
    }
  },
  "required": [ "Transaction" ]
}
```

Comment: Superb.  Confirmed as working and I can adapt this.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

All of your schemas are in definitions, but you don't actually reference them. So the "main" schema does nothing, therefore everything is valid.

Try moving the "Schema" definition out of $defs into the main body (just outdent it two levels).

Comment: Thanks @Ether I have tried the following but still no joy (assuming this is what you meant)? {   "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",   "type": "object",   "additionalProperties": false,   "properties": {     "Transaction": {       "$ref": "#/$defs/Transaction"     }   },   "$defs": {     "Transaction": {